# Configuring a ModuleType with the SDK option in the beginning

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone, intellij-plugin

In my plugin I was able to build a new project wizard but the first page doesn't look right. E.g. this is what my plugin has:

[image: My plugin]

And this is what most other plugins have:

[image: Other plugins]

The thing that's missing for me is the "SDK" option. Our plugin requires Java 8 and I'd like the option to pick an SDK to show up there. But I don't understand where that's configured.

This is in my `plugins.xml`:

```xml
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
   <!-- moduleBuilder builderClass="com.codename1.plugin.intellij.module.CodenameOneModuleType"/ -->
   <moduleType id="CodenameOne.Module" implementationClass="com.codename1.plugin.intellij.module.CodenameOneModuleType" classpathProvider="true"  />
</extensions>
```

`CodenameOneModuleType` just extends `ModuleType<NewCodenameOneProject>` where `NewCodenameOneProject` is basically a `JavaModuleBuilder`. I can post some more sources if that would help.

BTW is there a javadoc for the plugin API's?

I know where the sources are but is there no ready made JavaDoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a totally clear solution to this but I did reach several conclusions based on the discussion [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206575419-Setting-up-an-SDK-and-Language-Version-for-new-Project?page=1#community_comment_207578149):

- Setting the SDK for the project should be done via: `ProjectRootManager.getInstance(project).setProjectSdk(jdk);`
- Instead of overriding `createWizardSteps` which starts on the second page of the wizard I can just override the first page by using `getCustomOptionsStep`

Once I understood those I just recreated the combo box UI above using the IntelliJ/IDEA gui builder and some logic:

```
private void refreshSDKCombo(Sdk preferredSdk) {
    DefaultComboBoxModel<Sdk> sdks = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    Sdk[] s = ProjectJdkTable.getInstance().getAllJdks();
    for (Sdk ss : s) {
        if (ss.getSdkType() instanceof JavaSdkType) {
            String str = ss.getVersionString();
            if (str.contains("1.8.") || str.contains("1.9.")) {
                sdks.addElement(ss);
            }
        }
    }
    if(preferredSdk != null) {
        String str = preferredSdk.getVersionString();
        if (str.contains("1.8.") || str.contains("1.9.")) {
            projectSDKCombo.setSelectedItem(preferredSdk);
        }
    }
    projectSDKCombo.setModel(sdks);
    if(sdks.getSize() > 0) {
        projectSDKCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
}
```

Noticed I limited the options to JDK 8+ which is required for our use case!

I bound the button logic to configure the SDK as such:

```
    newButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        ProjectJdksEditor editor = new ProjectJdksEditor((Sdk)projectSDKCombo.getSelectedItem(),
                ProjectManager.getInstance().getDefaultProject(),
                newButton);
        if (editor.showAndGet()) {
            Sdk selectedJdk = editor.getSelectedJdk();
            refreshSDKCombo(selectedJdk);
        }
    });
```